# I want to remove several tabpages from my TabControl in my C# project. How can I do that in a shorter way, instead of removing each tab one by one?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TabControl in my C# form. According to the program step I have to remove a range of the tabs programmaticaly. I do that currently in this way, but with changing conditions I have to remove the tabpages always one by one.

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage5);
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage6);
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage7);
// remove other tabs
```

I want to be able to remove the tabs in a shorter way, in a loop something like that: Here Instead of the ??? I want to  write the tabpage(n) indirectly with a variable. Is that possible?

```
for(int n=start; n<=stop; n++)
{    
    tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(???)
}
```

Comment: You could use [`RemoveAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.tabpagecollection.removeat?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-forms-tabcontrol-tabpagecollection-removeat(system-int32)) but you might need to express it as _"remove {count} tab pages starting from index {index]"_ as removing a tab page will change the indexes

Comment: @stuartd Is it not possible to define the "tabpagex" as a control and define the control name dynamicaly?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it not possible to define the "tabpagex" as a control and define
> the control name dynamicaly?

Sure, you can SEARCH for controls "by name" using `Controls.Find(name, true)`:

```
int start = 5;
int stop = 8;
for (int n = start; n <= stop; n++)
{
    TabPage tb = this.Controls.Find("tabPage" + n, true).FirstOrDefault() as TabPage;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tabControl1.Controls.Remove(tb);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the life of me, I couldn't figure out what that comment meant.